# how move pdf field with pdfbox?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

i'm trying to align pdf fields to the first on the row. I'm able to get fields and its position. I'm also able to locally change it but when i save pdf the fields appears on the same position.
this is the code:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("MyFile"));
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
String fieldName = "MyField";
PDField f = acroForm.getField(fieldName);
PDRectangle r = f.getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
r.setLowerLeftX(10);
r.setLowerLeftY(10);
r.setUpperRightX(10);
r.setUpperRightY(10);

pdfDocument.save(new File("MyModifiedFile"));
pdfDocument.close();
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, then please clarify what PDFBox version are you using, and upload the PDF file somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reassign the modified rectangle to the widget:

```
f.getWidgets().get(0).setRectangle(r);
```

Because unlike the widget, the rectangle is not backed by the structures in the PDF.